# If the target of a Scrying spell succeeds on the saving throw against the spell, who is prevented from using the spell on them for the next 24 hours?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, homebrew, divination

The description of the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell states in part that:

> On a successful save, the target isn't affected, and you can't use
> this spell against it again for 24 hours.

However, this seems a bit ambiguous. Is only that character unable to use the spell on that target for 24 hours? Or can no one in the party use it on the target during that time? Does the source of the *scrying* matter?

For instance, consider a party that has a *scrying eye* homebrew magic item. A *scrying eye* is an item that allows a person to cast the *scrying* spell for up to ten minutes with a spell save DC of 15. It can only be used once per day, and then cannot be used again until the next dawn.

My homebrew *scrying eye* item is based off the official [*crystal ball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/crystal-ball) magic item:

> The typical *crystal ball*, a very rare item, is about 6 inches in diameter. While touching it, you can cast the *scrying* spell (save DC 15) with it.

I have lowered the spell save DC from the original to account for my item not requiring attunement.

The party has 2 spellcasters who both know the *scrying* spell.

If player A uses the *scrying eye* and fails, can they then cast *scrying* themselves again, as it is in effect the item that cast the spell and not the player? Can player B also attempt to cast *scrying*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The *scrying* attempt is based on the caster

The words are a bit confusing, but I'm going to highlight the important bits from your quotes of the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell description:

> On a successful save, the target isn't affected, and **you** can't use this spell against it again for 24 hours.

and of the [*crystal ball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/crystal-ball):

> [...] **you** can cast the *scrying* spell (save DC 15) with it.

The spellcasting is tied to whomever cast it. If Player A fails, then player B can still attempt. Using the same magic item does not change that.

Comment: what about the use of a magic item, is the user still seen as 'you' and therefore unable to cast it as a spell? happy to mark this as the answer if you can clarify that point :)

Comment: @RichardC Most magic items utilize the language of casting as if you had cast. Can you add the specifics of the item to your question?

Comment: it is somthing I have created based off the crystal ball, link added

Answer (score 5):

### “You” is used in second person singular form

That is, “you” is the person casting *Scry* right now against which the target successfully saved. This follows from the fact that any instance of casting the *Scry* spell only has a singular caster.

If 2 casters cast the spell (whatever the source) then the second caster is not the “you” of the first casting and vice-versa.